# Still getting `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop` even when I have a unique key assigned to the outermost element

Tags: reactjs

I'm sure I'm missing something dumb, but I'm still getting a `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop` error even after assigning a key to my outermost tag in my loop.

Here's the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGetProductsList } from '../api/ProductsApi';

function Products(props){
  const productsQuery = useGetProductsList();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="text-purple-500 p-10">
        { (productsQuery.isSuccess || productsQuery.isLoading) && (
          productsQuery.products.map((product) => (
            <div key={product.productId} className="flex space-x-5">
              <p>{product.style}</p>
              <p>{product.name}</p>
            </div>
          )))
        }
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

Any thoughts as to what's going on here? I know my `productId` values are all unique and I've also tried `productsQuery.products.map((product, index)` and using index as well and neither work.

I've even tried something like this:

```html
    <p key={`${product.style}${product.productId}`}>{product.style}</p>
    <p key={`${product.name}${product.productId}`}>{product.name}</p>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You sure you are getting error from here? Because code and other approaches mentioned should work, if you say your productId are unique.

Comment: Like Sagar said, the error might not be coming from this part of the code. Where else are you mapping an array to components?

Comment: Yes, if I comment out the code above, the error goes away. I have manually checked the keys and double checked what’s coming in from react-query Dev tools. Really odd